# emacs: kill a buffer and remove it from the buffer list

Tags: emacs

In Emacs, when a buffer is killed, it is still displayed on the buffer list (though it's empty after opening it from the list). 
Is is possible to remove the buffer from the buffer list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just refresh the buffer list by pressing <kbd>g</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks @choroba! I see it now disappears form the list, but is still present in the "strap", i.e. when you select via C-x b. I guess it's related to history?

Comment: @Tomek: What do you mean by the "strap"? I don't see the killed buffer's name anywhere.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should be more specific. What I meant is that if you use C-x b, rather than C-x C-b, the buffer selection happens in one line at the bottom of the screen, rather than in a separate window. The buffers in the line are selected with the up/down arrows. And this is where I still see the name of the killed buffer.

Comment: @Tomek: Up/down arrows are for history browsing, not buffer selection. Press `tab` for completion.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to achieve it automatically:

```
(defun my-kill-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (kill-buffer)
  (if (get-buffer "*Buffer List*")
      (save-excursion
        (set-buffer "*Buffer List*")
        (revert-buffer))
))
```